# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5) into shape (4) while performing row operations on Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a pandas dataframe (data) which has 2 columns containing list of words (example below):

[image: data]

When I run the code below:

```
data['uncommon_words']= data.apply(lambda row: list(set(row['col1']) - set(row['col2'])), axis=1)
```

I get the error message:
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5) into shape (4)

Can anyone help me resolve this error. I have already checked multiple other similar posts but could not find the solution for this. I am using Python 3.5.2

Comment: Those do not look to be lists but actual stings as there are no quotes wrapped by elements.